# Rails, link_to ... treatments/_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

At the time im refactoring my rails application:

Normally i simply render partial forms, like this:

```
 <%= render "treatments/form" %>
```

So now i tried to display this partial on another site, with an link:

```
 <%= link_to 'new', "treatments/form" %>
```

But get the error:

```
  No route matches [GET] "/patients/treatments/form"
```

I know that i have to edit my routes but i dont know how?

```
 Ruble::Application.routes.draw do
resources :patients do
  resources :treatments
  resources :paintings
end

resources :treatments do
  resources :categories
end
```

So what can i do, to get it work?
How can i generate an link to the same partial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All your links must match a route/controller action. A partial is just a file.

Why would you like to refactor `<%= render "treatments/form" %>`? It's perfectly fine.

But if you really want to, you can do a `render` in your controller action.

Comment: Ok i see! But how should i define the route/controller action?

Comment: Depends what url you want etc, but normally you would use the `new` action in your treatments controller. And render your partial inside treatments/new.html.erb